# KIE Server not deploying on WildFly 10

Tags: activemq-classic, drools, wildfly-10, drools-guvnor, kie

Hi I am trying to get the KIE Server distribution running on WildFly 10, found here:

http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Final/kie-server-distribution-6.3.0.Final.zip

It fails as described in this ticket:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-925

There is a proposed and declined pull request, with the argument that this would break WildFly 8 & 9. However, the proposed PR does not even work in WildFly 10 for me.

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/pull/195

Is there a workaround to get this running on WildFly 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KieServer 6.5.0 and newer run on Wildfly 10(.1)